# Подскажите библиотеки на разные цвета Python 3.5

Tags: color, python-3.5

Здравствуйте, пожалуйста подскажите библиотеку Python 3.5 на большое количество цвета в Python.(не colorama там мало) Буду весьма благодарен. Желательно ASCII кодировки. Использую Windows 10 PRO 32-bit

Comment: Что такое "большое количество цвета в Python" ?

Comment: BLUE, GREY, RED и т.д чтоб консоль была цветной, а не чорно0белой

Comment: @EvleapsCorp., в colorama есть и BLUE, и GREY, и RED, и т.д. Консоль под Windows поддерживает 16 цветов для текста и 8 цветов для фона. Если нужно больше, то вам нужно обычное (не консольное) окно, в котором уже можно рисовать любым оттенком, который поддерживает ваш комп и система.

Comment: Роль colorama модуля, чтобы переносимый код писать. [До Windows 10](https://goo.gl/U6UKEv), чтобы цвет в консоли получить, используя один и тот же код на Unix и Windows, можно [ANSI & VT100 escape кода](https://goo.gl/ugEsLu) использовать и вызывать `colorama.init()`, чтобы она эти кода перевела в соответствующие win32 вызовы (правда виндовая консоль всё равно только 16 цветов поддерживает). Вы можете хоть руками строки с кодами создавать, хотя удобней и более читаемо использовать [библиотеку по вкусу](https://goo.gl/Z2EBDq)